# the Layout is wrap-content but it doesn't wrap it

Tags: android

in the attached picture you see that the selected Text View has wrap-content for its Width but the text inside it which is "TextView" is not wrapped, why?

[image]

Comment: Please add the layout code.

Comment: please share xml code....

Comment: Please share your xml code.

Answer (score 1):

Check your margin and padding attributes for the textView, set them both to 0dp.